# Passing PHP variables to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying my best to learn AJAX and passing these php variables through to another php file. I am struggling though with some code.

Here is my problem. I have a button when onClick that does a javascript function

```
<input type='image' src='images/download-all.png' alt='Submit' onclick='download(".$y['imageURL'].")'>
```

The $y['imageURL'] is from code that pulls in results from a table.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM digital_materials WHERE id = '".$x['itemID']."'";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$y = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1);
```

Because I am running a while loop before hand I get two arrays back, that both have imageURL keys. I am partially using someone else's code here, so if there is something just point it out.

Here is my download function.

```
function download(x)
    {
        $.ajax({
                url:'download.php',
                data:"image="+x,
                success:function(e){
                        alert("Hey, this worked.");
                },
                error:function(e, f, g){
                    alert("Error removing from cart, please try again. "+e+" : "+f+" : "+g);
                }
        });
    }
```

How do I pass both of these keys from the array to my php file to be processed? Right now it is just giving me this on my source code.

Comment: You need to echo the variable...

Comment: Doing a var dump of $y['imageURL'] gives me two filenames.

string(24) "Infinity.jpg" string(43) "Diamond.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send arrays in query strings like that

```
image[first]=image.jpg&image[second]=image.png
```

You will then be able to access each image through PHP super variable `$_GET` or `$_POST` depending on the method set on your ajax request (I think it's `$_GET` by default with jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Missing `<?php  ?>` no ?

```
<input type='image' src='images/download-all.png' alt='Submit' onclick='download("<?php echo $y['imageURL']; ?>")'>
```

Comment: There is php tags wrapped around it. I just did not post it.

Comment: Have you tried to use json encode with json_encode($y) ? And then to pass your json variable to ajax ??

Comment: No, I have not. I'll look at that.

Comment: Ok I think it would be good with json. And use json_decode() in your download.php